# parsing json and showing in grid view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, json

I m parsing a json url and showing it in a grid view.The output in the simulator  looks like a grid of images similar to imagepicker.on pressing the image it got to navigate to a new view...the code works fine and i am able to receive the data in the console when the image is clicked.the problem is i m not able to navigate to the next view..cud u guys help me out

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    jsonurl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.1040communications.net/sheeba/stepheni/iphone/stephen.json"];
    jsonData=[[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:jsonurl];
    jsonArray = [jsonData JSONValue]; 
    items = [jsonArray objectForKey:@"items"];
    //  NSLog(@"hello:%@",items);
    story = [[NSMutableArray array]retain];
    media1 = [[NSMutableArray array]retain];

    for (NSDictionary *item in items )
    {
        [story addObject:[item objectForKey:@"title"]];
        [media1 addObject:[item objectForKey:@"media"]];    
    }

    UIScrollView *view = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < media1.count; i++) {
        NSString *mel=[media1 objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *escapedURL = [mel stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        UIImage *thumb = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:escapedURL]]];
        button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(column*100+24, row*80+10, 64, 64);
        [button setImage:thumb forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self 
                   action:@selector(buttonClicked:) 
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.tag = i; 
        [view addSubview:button];

        if (column == 2) {
            column = 0;
            row++;
        } else {
            column++;
        }
    }

    [view setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, (row+1) * 80 + 10)];
    self.view = view;
    [view release];
}

- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    UIImage *boy = [story objectAtIndex:button.tag];
    Detailview *detailview=[[Detailview alloc]init];
    [detailview initWithItem:boy];
    self.detailviewController=detailview;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailviewController animated:YES];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi looks like ur using old JSON parser. there is a much better parser for json.

thats [JSONKIT](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit).

It has just 2 files(.h and .m) and in just 2 lines of code u can get any data corresponding to the key. u dont hav to iterate through your items array. ur performance rate will definetly incr using JSONKit. if u tryin to use this let me i can post sample codes to parse json contents using jsonkit.

Secondly for the problem u have, u are putting the images in UIScrollview. ur uiscrollview doesnt have navigationcontrol to be pushed to the next view. either remove the scroll view and push from the rootviewcontroller or add navigationcontroller to uiscrollview. guess thats the prob. try it.

all the best.

Comment: thanks,cud u gimme some sample code on jsonKit...about scroll view i ll giv a check...

Comment: NSDictionary *dict = [webData objectFromJSONData]; 
items = [dict objectForKey:@"items"];

similarly u can extrat any value in the array from the dictionary.

Comment: :i assume the webdata to be NSDictionary.....thanks for the code man...i tried removing the scroll view but still not able to navigate...cud u help me out..i m ready to even giv de entire project

Comment: webData is the response json u get from net. it of type NSData not nsdictionary. 
try doing this [self.view addSubview:scrollview] instead of self.view=view. and remove scrollview in the method u have called.
when u give self.view=view u r equating the rootviewcontroller to another view which might be causing the problem. so jus add scrollview on top of the existing view. before that u are workin on navigation-based application or view based application???

Comment: yup...i ve implemented [self.view addSubview:Scrollview]..but still  not able to navigate

Comment: u are workin on navigation-based application or view-based application??? - (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender --> in this method u r removing scrollview rite???
do 1 thing remove ur scrollview code(don even add it) and jus try to navigate from the view. u will get to know if prob is with the view or scrollview.
other option u can try is add navigationcontroller to ur scrollview also and try pushing it to next view

Comment: i m using a view based application...i removed the scroll view completely but still de same...i ll post ma code...http://pastie.org/2319400

Comment: have u connected the navigation controller in xib??? y cant u use navigation-based app then u don have to worry about the connections and al. anyways jus check ur connections once in xib.

Comment: try giving this after ur scrollview initialisation. view.navigationController=self.navigationcoller ( don remove scrollview in that method)
and what does this line mean??  Detailview *detailview=[[Detailview alloc]init]; don u have a xib for that view??? shdnt it be this--> Detailview *detailview=[[Detailview alloc]initWithNibName:Detailview bundle:nil]; does ur Detailview have any init method in it???? u havent showed DetailView class in u code.

Comment: below is the code for DetailView....http://pastie.org/2323645..its the contination of the above code..

Comment: i tired view.navigationController=self.navigationController....i m getting error...i m initalizing detailview..with detailview as object I m calling the function initWithITem and initWithItem1..and able to receive the data in my console (if i m to place an nslog in the above two functions in my detail view)...as far navigation i tried adding navbar in my xib...but still no use...

Comment: ur link doesnt open. check it up and give the correct link.
im not sure if this line is the rite way to give [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];

Comment: ur not even calling the view. in ur init method ur jus transferring this view to next. thats the prob. when u navigate there is no view. i tried ur code its wrokin fyn in my side. i tried in navigation based project and i didn give ur webservices i just tried with hardcoded values. Ur aim is to send the boy array to detailview rite??

Comment: yup dats rite...one thing i want to clarify if u r to choose navigation based application at the beggining of the project..wont u get table view

Comment: http://pastie.org/2323756 u can check it out. ur using xib only to show ur view rite. so its simple goto ur xib remove the tableview and add a normal view and connect the view to file manager. in ur rootview change from uitableview to uiview it will work. i can mail u the proj if u want. i have changed the initial view from tableview to a normal view.

Comment: my aim is not to just show the next view .. im passing the data to the next view...and well as my next view got to be seen

Comment: :i chose a navigation control i opened the RootViewController.xib...i deleted the table view..and put a new UIview...wat i m to do next...

Comment: jus connect the file manager view to ur view. n run the code.

Comment: dude i m a noob....is der any possibility of u givin ur no...i wanna clarify something abt de .xib file...

Comment: thanks cancerian...i owe u a huge favour that worked...i used navigation based app instead of view based application....i was able to navigate to the next view....one more thing want to clarify..is JSONKIT faster than SBJSON..

Comment: wow gud :) yes jsonkit is faster than sbjson. no of fiels in the lib is less and implementation is also easy compared to sbjson.

Comment: even in jsonKit i m in need of iterating for loop....i ve hav one small problem...de images are getting loaded pretty slow any idea...?

Comment: yup...check ma code...if i m dont iterate using for loop..i m bound to get  error..http://www.pastie.org/2324742

Comment: don iterate same way as items get other data.
 story = [dict objectForKey:@"title"];

Comment: dude i tried ur above code.."story = [dict objectForKey:@"title"]" still getting null values

Comment: im not able to view the page. jus give me the request line u sending. i wil try in my code

Comment: page is blocked. jus give me the request line u sending. i wil try in my code

Comment: nsdictionary *itemDict=[webData objectFromJSONData];
nsarray *titlArray = [itemDict valueForKey:@"title"];
nsarray *lnkArray=[itemDict valueForKey:@"link"];
same way get other data also

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your buttonClicked:

```
UIImage *boy = [story objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
```

You want the tag of `sender`, not `button`. `button` was set to the last one in your list when your buttons were created. `sender` is the ui object that caused this event.

Comment: Agreed. It makes no sense in this context to have `button` be an ivar. It just refers to the "last button created" which is just causing confusion. It should be a local variable.

Comment: @dean:thanks dude it worked...assigned the sender to a local variable

Comment: @dean:i got stuck into another problem..if i click the button ... i m able to receive url corresponding to the selected image in the console..but in simulator i m not able to navigate to de next page....any idea

Comment: You could ask a question on stack overflow with some example code ;)